# get last auto increment php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having an issue with my program where it calls questions column(questions) one at a time from my database table starting with id=1, id=2, id=3 and so on. Id is Auto_increment. When I delete a id from the database, my program messes up.

Database

```
    id     question
    1     Php?
    2     HTML?
    3     CSS?
    4     Java?
```

Webpage should display as such

```
#1 Php?
#2 HTML?
#3 CSS?
#4 Java?
```

The problem happens when I delete or add a question with an id out of order or missing

```
        id     question
        1     Php?
        2     HTML? <--- 3 is deleted and webpage messes up.
        4     Java?
        5     Oracle
        6     C++
```

How would I fix this problem where id will always be id=1,2,3,4,5,6...n and make sure when I add a new question at the bottom, the id will be last_id+1 using php and mysql?

---

I don't think I explained my problem correctly.

I'll see if I can fix one thing at a time.

If I have an id column in my database with id=1,2,3,4,5,6, how would I call the last id which last id=6 in the database if I've already deleted id=7,8? When I insert a new question the question id will be id=9 because of auto increment. I want the new question's id to be id=7. Maybe I can get help to fix this issue first.

Comment: Why do you want to display the IDs? Could you get by with an <ol> tag?

Comment: The easier solution would probably be to fix your program so that it doesn't mess up, rather than reorder every entry when you delete a row. Since you didn't go into any explanation about how it "messes up" though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to differentate between the id as the primary key, and the sequence number of the row.

Try this out:

```
SELECT
  id, question,
  @seq:=@seq+1 AS seq
FROM
  questions,
  (SELECT @seq:=0) AS init
;
```

You can now use seq to show the number, always in correct sequence, but make sure, that you associate your actions with the **id**, not the sequence, so you can reference the rwo by PK.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new element at id=3. Or you could just leave the id's alone and have it print out the value and have an integer value that increments every time a value is printed instead of printing out the id.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following example in your case. Here you can declare a variable and increment it in the loop.

```
$questions = array('PHP?', 'HTML?', 'CSS?', 'JAVA?');

$i = 1;
foreach($questions as $question)
{
    echo "#" . $i . " " . $question. "<br/>";
    $i++;
}
```