# re-assigning mysql user id

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure if it is possible but is there a way to re-assign an attribute 'id' in a database, Such as id=1,2,3,4,5,6 (6 elements), then id=3 is deleted, so when you look in the database your 'id' is re-assigned back in order like. id=1,2,3,4,5 (5 elements after id=3 is deleted). My 'id' attribute is auto_increment.

```
id    Name
1     A
2     B
3     C
4     D
5     E
6     F
```

then id=3 is deleted

```
id    Name
1     A
2     B<--   3 is deleted
4     D<--   name C is deleted
5     E
6     F
```

I then want to re-assign id back in order

```
id    Name
1     A
2     B
3     D
4     E
5     F
```

I can't find a way to get this done. I hope you can help.

Comment: why do you want that?

Comment: _“I can't find a way to get this done.”_ – it __should not__ be done. An id has the one single purpose of identifying a record, nothing else.

Comment: I understand that every one advise against it but I was given a program and for some reason the program only works when the id is in order without any breaks starting at id=1,2,3,4,5,6 and so on. I've tried changing the program and I've gotten no where. I do know if I'm able to re-assign the id then my program would work.

Comment: Theoretically could you just fix the other program?

Comment: possible duplicate of [get last auto increment php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394546/get-last-auto-increment-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First think carefully if you really need this. In my practice I've never had to rebuild the order of a table with auto increment column.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 AS (SELECT `Name` FROM `table1`);
TRUNCATE `table1`;
INSERT INTO `table1` (`Name`) (SELECT `Name` FROM table2)
```

This won't work if you have any foreign keys in your table

Answer (score 1):

If using a [*surrogate* KEY/PK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key), treat it as a *surrogate key* - that is, the value is "of no importance" other than it guaranteed to be unique per the relation domain.

That is, it is *merely an implementation detail* with no relation to data - trying to "compact" this sequence or otherwise use it for sequential ordering violates this.

To "compact" an auto_increment PK column, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488650/how-to-update-the-id-column-starting-from-1-again/22489808#22489808) (as compaction is required to "reset" the auto_increment seed). However, I advise *against* this because it violates a surrogate PK column, as per my previous comment.

---

Now, all the above aside, I believe one solution *might* be to introduce a sequence number *in* the queries that are otherwise "making the program break" - depending upon how the program is fed data, what it uses it for, and how it breaks, of course.

```
SET @i := 0;
SELECT
    (@i := (@i+1)) as seqNo
  , name
FROM people
ORDER BY id
```

This sequence number (`seqNo`) only relates to the row number *in that result set* and could otherwise be generated client-side as well - it is *not* related to the ID, although the ID is used to guarantee a *stable ordering*.

Comment: I understand that every one advise against it but I was given a program and for some reason the program only works when the id is in order without any breaks starting at id=1,2,3,4,5,6 and so on. I've tried changing the program itself to except any id number out of order and I've gotten no where. I do know if I'm able to re-assign the id then my program would work

Comment: @Jordan The *correct* solution is to fix the program (and find out why it breaks). In any case, my linked answer contains the solution for "compaction" - however, such will have to be done after *any* gap is introduced as is thus a *poor patch*, even as a temporary hack.